# How to insert the data into a table with different number of columns in SQL

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite, sql-insert

I'm trying to copy the data from one table to other. Please find the below code:

```
//Dummy table for reference
database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `New_Temp1` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `data1` TEXT DEFAULT '', `data2` INTEGER NOT NULL, `data3` TEXT DEFAULT '', `data4` TEXT DEFAULT '', `data5` TEXT DEFAULT '')");
database.execSQL("INSERT INTO New_Temp1 SELECT * FROM Temp1");
database.execSQL("DROP TABLE Temp1");
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE New_Temp1 RENAME TO Temp1");
```

The **Temp1** table is already there in database. I don't know the schema of that. Means I don't know the columns of that table. So I am creating a new table **New_temp1**. When I try to copy the data from Temp1 to New_Temp1, application crashes.

```
**Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table New_Temp1 has 33 columns but 28 values were supplied (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO New_Temp1 SELECT * FROM Temp1**
```

How to solve this, I don't know which columns are missing in Temp1 table.

Comment: You created New_Temp1 with 33 columns and you want to copy 28 columns from Temp1. If you don't know which column should be copied to which column then you can't do it.

Comment: @forpas Can I get to know which columns that I am missing?

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This statement raises the error:

```
INSERT INTO New_Temp1 SELECT * FROM Temp1
```

It looks like the target table does not have the same columns as the original (there are more columns in the target).

If you want to copy the table without knowing the structure, you can combine the table creation and the copy in a single statement like that:

```
CREATE TABLE New_Temp1 AS
SELECT * FROM Temp1
```

On the other hand, if you don't want to copy all the columns, and you know the corresponding column names in the source table, then you can enumerate them in the `select` clause:

```
INSERT INTO New_Temp1 (data1, data2, data3)
SELECT data1, data2, data3 FROM Temp1
```

Comment: But I want all the columns in table New_Temp1.

Comment: I don't know the column names for temp1.

Comment: Is there a way to add copy all the data from Temp1 to new_temp along with new columns of Temp1.

Comment: @Archana: that's the second part of my answer. You need to enumerate the columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the column names of the table `Temp1` with this query:

```
SELECT name FROM pragma_table_info('Temp1')
```

You can execute the above statement with `rawQuery()` and by iterating through the rows of the cursor you will have all the column names and you can use them to create the new table.

If you execute:

```
SELECT * FROM pragma_table_info('Temp1')
```

you will get additional info for each column, like:

```
cid name    type    notnull dflt_value  pk
0   column1 INTEGER 0       0
1   column2 INTEGER 0       0
...........................................
```